# Асинхронность в одном потоке и "подготовленные" SQL-запросы (prepared statement)

Tags: sql, база-данных, асинхронность

Возможно ли это вообще? Пожалуйста, пример на любом языке и с любой БД. Потому что я посмотрел C API SQLite, MySQL, Postgres, и везде план действий (и структуры соответствующих данных) таков:

1. Подготовка запроса
2. Привязка к **подготовленному запросу** переменных
3. Обработка в цикле
4. Завершение

Только после завершения подготовленный запрос можно использовать повторно. А нужно так:

1. Подготовка запроса
2. Привязка переменных и подготовленного запроса к **контексту** выполнения, который, возможно, резервируется автоматически
3. Запуск подготовленного запроса с первым набором параметров (первый контекст)
4. Запуск подготовленного запроса с вторым набором параметров (второй контекст)
5. Получение данных в произвольном порядке
6. Завершение обоих запросов в произвольном порядке (освобождение структур контекстов)

Это, вроде бы, так просто и логично. Почему все БД вяжут параметры непосредственно к структуре, содержащей виртуальный код, в который скомпилирован ("подготовлен") SQL-запрос?

Answer (score 2):

Привет, у тебя че-то несколько важных понятий спутано.

Во-первых везде так потому что это классика и все прогеры как-то умудряются работать с этим.

Во-вторых ты зачем-то выдумал какой-то контекст, нету такого нигде и не было никогда. Есть "курсоры", объекты инкапсулирующие результаты выполнения.

В-третьих, асинхронность это что? Это неблокирующие вызовы и коллбэки. Так на даннный момент из известных языков устроен только яваскрипт. Коллбэков в принципе хватает и в классических языках, а вот неблокирующей логики там как-то не попадалось. Нет, в принципе в последнее время и в Python и в C# и ещё кое-где начали появляться примитивы для асинхронности, но это все пока медленно и в пробном режиме.

Ну и в четвертых, твоя проблема классически решается многопоточным дизайном приложения, в каждом отдельном потоке можешь даже своё соединение с БД завести.
Если потоки не хочется, можно сделать многопроцессное приложение с помощью fork

И ещё, получение данных в произвольном порядке - такое видимо пришло тебе в голову после общения с яваскриптовым аяксом. Там по-другому и не бывает. 
А вот в классических языках получение данных от SQL-запроса идет только в ожидаемом последовательном и линейном порядке, потому как классические языки программирования синхронные и блокирующие.

Comment: А как два result set на одном запросе, но с разными параметрами, использовать параллельно? Кстати, JS не является асинхронным языком, поскольку асинхронность в нем реализуется обратными вызовами (ну плюс замыкания), это и в C так же делается.

Answer (score 1):

Подготовленный запрос исключительно для того, что бы можно было избежать многократного компилирования текста запроса. С другой стороны, это самое компилирование происходит быстро. Не на столько, что бы можно было себе позволить выполнять его тысячи раз, когда достаточно одного, но и не на столько, что бы вообще отказаться от повторной компиляции. Посему вам надо в каждом "контексте" подготовить отдельный запрос, пусть даже и с одним и тем же текстом. Это в любом случае займет меньше времени, чем создание "контекста", т.е. например запуск потока.

И кстати, текст запроса скомпилирован не в этой структуре. Эта структура нужна в основном для общения клиента с СУБД, что бы помнить на каком месте закончили передачу по сети. Компиляция происходит на стороне сервера, в структуре связанной с вашим подготовленным запросом. И многие СУБД при повторной компиляции запроса с тем же текстом не проводят всю работу заново, а берут уже скомпилированный запрос из кеша. Так что разделение понятий, которое вы хотели увидеть на клиенте, существует, но на стороне сервера.

Почему так сделано ? Потому, что этого достаточно для решения любых задач. Излишне усложнять вызовы, вводя дополнительный слой нет особого смысла. В 95% случаев запрос подготавливается, данные получаются и обрабатываются. Загружаются новые параметры и опять выполняется. Если же надо читать по очереди то из одного то из другого однотипного запроса, то это так же не вызывает никаких затруднений. Подготавливаем два запроса с одинаковым текстом, привязываем в ним параметры, выполняем. После этого мы можем читать данные из каждого из них как угодно, хоть целиком все, хоть по одной строке то из одного, то из другого. По сути для программиста подготовленные запросы это всего лишь способ помнить на каком месте мы остановились.

Comment: А если сервера просто нет? А есть встраиваемая база Berkeley DB, сильно прокачанная Oracl'ом, которая сама по себе точно умеет то, что мне нужно, но натянутый на нее SQLite только лишь из-за своего интерфейса эту возможность уничтожает?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Если вам нравится интерфейс Berkeley, то и используйте ее. Что значит SQLite натянутый на нее ? Это разные СУБД. Лучше опишите, зачем вам понадобилось один и тот же запрос с разными параметрами выполнять одновременно. И чем вас не устраивает сделать prepare второй раз, если это практически не сказывается на ресурсах или вы заметили что сказывается и сильно ?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Про какие возможности Berkley вы говорите, которые вам нужны ? Там нет разделения чего бы то ни было на контексты, хотя бы по тому, что нет того, что можно было бы разделять